# Use proxy on VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I want to connect to a Proxy server but I can't because VPNs and proxies are fully blocked in my country.

However, I found a lot of VPN providers that can bypass the country block and it really works.. but I don't want the VPN, I want to connect to a proxy server using the VPN.

Is it possible? If no, is there's any solution to connect to a proxy server while I am being blocked by my country?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it!

I downloaded the SoftEther VPN client from here https://www.vpngate.net/en/download.aspx
and installed it.

Then after opening it.. I double clicked `VPN Gate Public VPN Relay Servers` then connected to a VPN server (using `Use TCP Protocol (Ethernet over HTTPS VPN)`) and it worked in my country.

Now I was able to connect to a proxy server behind this VPN.